# display text and image input inline in table

Tags: html, css, input

Hello I want to display a text and image input inside a table like this:

[image: expectations]

I've tried this code:

```
<tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="inputs">
                    <input type="text" id="input1" size="3"/>
                </td>
                <td class="inputs">
                    <input type="text" id="input2" />
                </td>
                <td class="inputs">
                    <input type="text" id="input3" size="10"/>
                </td>
                <td class="inputs">
                    <input type="text" id="input4" size="8"/>
                    <input type="image" src="button.png" />
                </td>
                <td class="inputs">
                    <input type="text" id="input5" size="10"/>
                </td>
                <td class="inputs">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="input6" />
                </td>
            </tr>
```

But the result is this:

[image: reality]

Any ideas how to fix this? Please help!

Comment: You should try setting the same `line-height` to the input elements (check also if `display:inline-block` is needed)

Answer (score 1):

Vertical alignment is the problem here. Simply specify `vertical-align: top` on your `input` elements within your table cells and they will all align to the same position (the top, in this case):

```css
td input {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```